# Syncing kindle book annotations (non Amazon books) across kindle apps

Tags: kindle, annotations, kindle-app

I buy Kindle Manning + O'Reilly books as they tend to be cheaper than the ones on Amazon. Can I sync annotations (e.g. notes, highlights) between Kindle apps (PC, tablet, etc.) ?

Comment: I have managed to do this via the new (?) "send to kindle" app offered by amazon. Books appear in amazon can can be delivered to portable device - not to PC apps though, which is a bit strange.

Comment: Amazon just got back to me saying that this feature is not supported at the moment (deliver 3rd party books via amazon site to PC kindle app). Of course, you can just open the 3rd party book but that does not synchronize annotations ... bit of a joke really amazon ...

Comment: It also works (but not on PC or cloud readers) if you email the ebook to your Kindle address.

Answer (score 3):

### Amazon Support said (on 2019-05-24) that syncing personal documents is not supported.

Here is my chat:

► Amazon: I'm sorry, currently there is no option to see the highlights made in the personal documents.

► Me: Ok, you are saying that Amazon deleted the website that allowed viewing highlights made in personal documents. Then I still have the other 2 questions:
1) Should Whispersync work to keep my reading "location" up to date between devices when reading personal documents (or is that not supported anymore either)?

2) Should Whispersync work to keep my highlights identical between devices when reading personal documents (or is that not supported anymore either)?

► Amazon: I can understand your concern. Please allow me a moment to check this.
Thanks for waiting.
I'm sorry, the highlights will not sync through all the devices which are made on personal documents.

► Me: And I guess the current reading "location" / progress won't either?

► Amazon: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use google there is an extension/app for kindle. I am a blogger and I review E books so it is very necessary for me to be able to use notes from a tablet to my pc and even on my phone. I have authors send me ARC books to review all the time. Use the app to send yourself the book in a pdf file. There are several free conversion sites online you can use and it just takes a second.

Just download the free app to everything you need it on including your PC and in setting activate the  Whispersync technology option. This makes your notes and books available on every device. Also you can send notes from your laptop to your kindle. Here is the link to the [Kindle PC](https://read.amazon.com/) version
here is the description of the app from [Google Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kindle-cloud-reader/icdipabjmbhpdkjaihfjoikhjjeneebd?hl=en)

Kindle Cloud Reader - Read Kindle books in your browser, and shop on Amazon.com.
Kindle Cloud Reader is a web app from Amazon that lets you read your Kindle books, instantly.

• Customize your reading experience by choosing font size, text color, background color, number of reading columns, and more
• Create and edit notes, highlights, and bookmarks
• Our Whispersync technology automatically syncs your furthest page read, notes, and marks across devices, so you can start reading in your browser and pick up where you left off on your Kindle or any device with the Kindle app installed
• Search inside the book to find a topic, character, or section you want to revisit
• Look up word definitions and listen to how they are pronounced (available for English only)
• Shop the Kindle Store for millions* of Kindle books, including new releases and bestsellers
• Your current book is automatically made available for offline use, and you can choose to save a book for reading offline at any time
• Receive automatic software updates without the need to download new software

I do not know if you are a Mac user or not, if so I am not familiar with if this is an option via apple or not. If you are a Google Chrome user however, there ya go, Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon now supports syncing notes on personal documents between Kindle devices and apps, but not the Kindle web-reader (read.amazon.com), as the web-reader does not show personal documents.